# Nodemailer Sending Email Getting Failed - Gmail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemailer

We are using `Nodemailer` to send emails automatically from our server. We are using gmail account to sending email. It works fine until yesterday night. Now we getting some error like

`{ Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.gmail.com at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19) errno: 'EREFUSED', code: 'EDNS', syscall: 'queryA', hostname: 'smtp.gmail.com', command: 'CONN' }`

I tried with some other gmail accounts also, it returning same error. Here is the code that we used

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    service: 'gmail',
                    port: 465,
                    secure: true,
                    auth: {
                        user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
                        pass: 'xxxxxxxx'
                    }
                });
```

Even I tried with code like

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                    auth: {
                        user: EmailPath["Email_UserName"],
                        pass: EmailPath["Email_Password"]
                    }

                });
```

Comment: It is generally not advisable to use Gmail as an SMTP provider for these types of use cases. Nodemailer recommends against it because Google "*runs a lot of heuristics for every login attempt and blocks anything that looks suspicious to defend the user from account hijacking attempts. For example you might run into trouble if your server is in another geographical location – everything works in your dev machine but messages are blocked in production.*" ([source](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/)).

Comment: Knowing the context you provided here it's likely Gmail is now blocking your machine; this is probably something that is more likely to be resolved by Google support teams than anyone else.

Comment: There are other email service providers. For example, sendgrid.com has a free tier and they do a good job.

Answer (score 0):

As @esqew mentioned, it is not advisable to use Gmail in Nodemailer. Google doesn't allow less secure apps to login to your account, however in most cases even enabling the "allow less secure apps" option doesn't resolve this issue.

There is a workaround to this, the solution is to use [app passwords](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB), however be cautious because anyone with your app password can log in to your Gmail account.

If you want to set up one for yourself, just follow the steps provided in the link above, you'll need to enable two factor authentication though. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, because app passwords worked for me, did you turn on the two factor authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Sending email with gmail and nodemailer you have to do 4 steps:

1. Google Account -> Security -> Section "Signing in to Google" -> Enable 2-Step Verification
2. When finsh the 1st step in Google Account -> Security -> Section "Signing in to Google" -> Create "App passwords"
3. When finish the 2 step you got an app password and you set it to a variable in your config file like app_password = "yourgooglepasswordhere"
4. Use the nodejs code as below

   *var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

   service:"Gmail",
   auth: {
   user: "xxxx@gmail.com",
   pass: config.email_app_password
   },
   });*

And now you can send email as nodemailer said:

https://nodemailer.com/about/

```
 let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: "bar@example.com, baz@example.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
  });
```